# Tesseract CLI hocr and tessdata-dir options not working together

Tags: command-line-interface, tesseract

I'm getting an error when trying to run this command

```
tesseract orig.jpg stdout --tessdata-dir dev/ -oem 4 hocr
read_params_file: Can't open hocr
```

However the following two examples work fine

1. Without tessdata-dir

   tesseract orig.jpg stdout -oem 4 hocr
2. Without hocr

   tesseract orig.jpg stdout --tessdata-dir dev/ -oem 4

I tried putting options in different orders, it doesn't help.
I'm using tesseract 4.00.00alpha on Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specify a full path to hocr config to make it work

```
tesseract orig.jpg stdout --tessdata-dir dev/ -oem 4 dev/tessdata/configs/hocr
```